# Qual a diferença de uso entre mouseClicked e actionPerformed?

Tags: java

Qual a diferença entre estes dois eventos: mouseClicked() e actionPerformed()? O que se difere na sua execução e quando eles serão executados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O evento [`mouseClicked()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)) faz parte da [Interface MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html), interface "ouvinte" dos eventos relacionados ao [mouse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) e controla os eventos do mesmo. Esse "ouvinte" é chamado quando o botão do mouse foi **clicado** (pressionado e liberado) em um componente.

O evento [`actionPerformed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)) faz parte da [Interface ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), interface "ouvinte" dos [eventos de ação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html)  e controladora das ações definidas de um componente. Esse "ouvinte", em linhas gerais, é chamado quando ocorre uma ação.

## Relacionada

- [Qual a diferença de uso entre KeyPressed e ActionPerformed?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233453/66203)

Answer (score 5):

O ActionPerformed irá responder quando o botão for acionado, seja pelo mouse ou pelo teclado, o MouseClicked só irá notificar quando o mouse for usado.

Fonte: [Diferença entre MouseClicked e ActionPerformed?](http://www.guj.com.br/t/diferenca-entre-mouseclicked-e-actionperformed/46499/2)

Comment: Foi mais rápido que eu :D