# Qual a diferença de uso entre KeyPressed e ActionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing

Fiz uns testes para ver a diferença de uso, e aparentemente ambos disparam ao pressionar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> no teclado, como pode ser visto no exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class KeyListenerActionPerformTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            KeyListenerActionPerformTest frame = new KeyListenerActionPerformTest();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public KeyListenerActionPerformTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.contentPane = (JPanel) getContentPane();

        this.panel = new JPanel();
        this.panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Campo c/ Action e KeyListener"));
        this.contentPane.add(this.panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.textField = new JTextField(10);

        this.textField.addActionListener(e -> {
            textArea.append("Action triggered.\n");
        });

        this.textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                textArea.append("KeyEvent triggered.\n");
            }
        });

        this.panel.add(this.textField);

        this.panel2 = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(this.panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.textArea = new JTextArea(5, 15);
        this.textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        this.panel2.add(this.scrollPane);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

E executando ao pressionar o enter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Diante disso, gostaria de deixar os seguintes questionamentos:

- Existe alguma diferença entre se usar `actionPerformed` ou `keyPressed`, por exemplo, num campo de texto?
- Há diferenças na forma como ambos executam?

Comment: O `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { }` é disparado quando você executa um evento como clicar com o mouse ou recortar o texto com o contextmenu?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não, somente enter via teclado.

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre Mouse Clicked e Action Performed?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212610/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-mouse-clicked-e-action-performed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Diferença de forma geral:

O *ActionPerformed* é utilizado para tratar qualquer evento que um usuário possa realizar. Exemplos: clicar em um botão, selecionar um item de menu ou pressionar enter num *text field*.

Então, por exemplo, se você adicionar o seguinte código no *JFrame*:

```
JButton testeAction = new JButton("Action");
testeAction.addActionListener(e -> {
    textArea.append("Action triggered.\n");
});
testeAction.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            textArea.append("KeyEvent triggered.\n");
        }
});
this.panel.add(testeAction);
```

Verá que toda vez que um usuario clicar no botão a mensagem "**Action triggered.**" será exibida.

KeyListener é utilizado para tratar eventos relacionados a teclas (Mais específico que ActionPerformed).

> Existe alguma diferença entre se usar actionPerformed ou KeyListener, por exemplo, num campo de texto?

No seu caso, em que será necessário apenas tratar o evento de tecla pressionada, não há diferença. Entretanto, imagine uma situação onde você tenha uma ação para o evento de pressionar a tecla e outra ação ao soltar a tecla pressionada:

```
this.textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        textArea.append("KeyReleased triggered.\n");
    }
});

this.textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        textArea.append("KeyPressed triggered.\n");
    }
});
```

Seria mais difícil fazer isso com um *ActionListener*.

> Há diferenças na forma como ambos executam ?

Ambos são *listeners* (Através da interface *EventListener*). Não existe uma diferença de execução entre os dois.

Comment: Boa resposta! :)

Answer (score 6):

`Keypressed` é um método da interface keylistener que herda de Eventlistener. O Actionperformed é um método da interface `ActionListener`, que recebe como parâmetro o ACTIONEVENT, que também herda de EventListener. Temos que analisar que ambos métodos recuperam eventos, porém o Actionperformed é mais genérico, sendo acionado com a ocorrência de qualquer tipo de evento na aplicação.

Ao analisarmos na documentação é explicado que o parametro que Actionperformed recebe ,UM ACTIONEVENT, TEM UM VALOR DEFAULT que eh a barra de espaço executando um ActionEvent em um botão.

A documentação diz assim:

> Um evento semântico que indica que ocorreu uma ação definida pelo
>   componente. Este evento de alto nível é gerado por um componente (como
>   um botão) quando ocorre a ação específica do componente (como ser
>   pressionada). O evento é passado para cada objeto ActionListener que
>   se registrou para receber esses eventos usando o método
>   addActionListener do componente.
>
> **Nota: Para invocar um ActionEvent em um botão usando o teclado, use a
>   barra de espaço.**
>
> O objeto que implementa a interface ActionListener obtém este
>   ActionEvent quando o evento ocorre. O ouvinte é, portanto, poupado os
>   detalhes do processamento de movimentos individuais do mouse e cliques
>   do mouse, e pode processar um evento "significativo" (semântico) como
>   "botão pressionado".
>
> Um comportamento não especificado será causado se o parâmetro id de
>   qualquer instância ActionEvent específica não estiver no intervalo de
>   ACTION_FIRST para ACTION_LAST.

Se tu nao especificar os parâmetros  ele vai receber ação default como parâmetro que está na ***nota*** da explicação da documentação.

O keypressed você vai conseguir manipular entradas do teclado tendo diversas opçoes para você poder ser mais especifico na programação dos eventos do teclado.

Eu acho que é isso me baseando nas documentações

Comment: É sempre interessante traduzir menções em inglês, :)

Comment: ah blz, traduzi o texto da documentação no tradutor, acho q atradução ficou legivel o que achou?

Comment: Da uma formatada nessa resposta, está muito confusa, e agora com a tradução, não da pra saber onde começa e termina a citação que você traduziu.

Comment: ficou confuso mesmo,não dava pra saber aonde terminava ou começava a citação,obrigado

Comment: Em um campo de texto não é a barra de espaço que dispara o Action, é sim o botão enter. Acho que a explicação fugiu um pouco da pergunta, e até deixou de responder a primeira dúvida. Aliás, lendo somente sua resposta, eu acho que nenhuma das duas perguntas é respondidas, ao menos não ficou claro pra mim.